# Is there a way to use apostrophes in sed commands?

Tags: shell-script, sed

Is there a way to use apostrophes `'` with the sed command?

I mean this: -

```
sed '-2 a\\
What's up?' text
```

I am talking about the apostrophe in "What's up". If I do it like this it gives me an error "Unmatched"

I tried to escape that apostrophe with `\` OR `\\` like this `What\'s up?`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: and to use an apostrophe in, e.g., a search pattern you can use the octal:  `\o047` - e.g. `sed -n -e '/\o047/p'` to print only lines containing an apostrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '2 a\ 
What'\''s up?' text
```

or

```
sed "2 a\ 
What's up?" text
```